# Update with "Text to Columns" every time the source file is updated

Tags: excel, vba

On export my legacy system removes from row columns with TOTALS Dollar sign Symbols  "$", and does not allow for DATES to transfer into SHEET2. I have tried to record a Text to Column process for including with vba script, however, Sheet1 transfers all data correctly into Sheet2, before script stops, 2 columns raise totals up by one row; and Text to Column VBA script does not do what I ask it to do in sequence.

```
Private Sub TextToColumn ()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim SHEET2 As Worksheet
Dim Results As Worksheet

Set Results = Sheets("SHEET2")
LastRow = Results.Cells(Results.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row

Range("A15:A400").Copy
Results.Range("A" & LastRow + 2).PasteSpecial xlValues
Range("B15:B400").Copy
Results.Range("B" & LastRow + 2).PasteSpecial xlValues
Range("J15:J400").Copy
Results.Range("C" & LastRow + 2).PasteSpecial xlValues
Range("R15:R400").Copy
Results.Range("D" & LastRow + 2).PasteSpecial xlValues

Application.DataEntryMode = False

Dim lrow As Long
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(lrow, 2)).TextToColumns 
  Destination:=Range("C2"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, 
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Semicolon:=True, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: You are not referencing the sheet for your cell/ranges.

Comment: Let me check. Thank you